# My model doesn't bind on my checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, scope

This is my checkbox. I have a model there named selAll.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAll(filteredTitles, cpPortfolioItem)" ng-model="selAll">
```

Now I have this button that needs to remove the checkmark on the checkbox.

```
<button class="btn-success btn " ng-click="updateTitleStatus(4)">
```

Note that I have some function on the ng-click of the button so I put `$scope.sellAll = false;` inside that function but the checkmark is still there even I pressed it. How can I uncheck the checkbox? Thanks.

Comment: Could you include some sample code on JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D#! is a good start

Comment: `ng-model` should always be bound to an object , not a primitive. If there is a child scope involved you will lose 2 way binding. *Always have a dot in ng-model*

Comment: spelling mistake in the model name - `sellAll != selAll`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4o9yxz02/1/

Comment: here is the link of an example https://jsfiddle.net/rexxar31/jfgn20gf/

Comment: @MixAustria see the above fiddle to see how you can create a angular demo... also whether fixing the spelling solved your issue.. else try to recreate the issue in my above fiddle

Comment: im not using the checkbox to change some data but I'm using the button to check or uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/jfgn20gf/1/

Comment: Thank you so much all. You gave me an idea. ~cheerio

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using the following logic to check and uncheck the checkbox based on the previous state `$scope.selAll = !$scope.selAll` in the ng-click function of the button

Here is the working plunker with your code

http://embed.plnkr.co/MjOGNxot8P1OO9DcmuER/preview

Hope this helps!!!!!!